# JSON structure not surviving conversion round trip

Tags: json, powershell

This command:

```
ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json '{ "abc": [ [1, 2, 3], 4, [5, 6, 7] ] }')
```

returns:

```
{ "abc":  [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, [ 5, 6, 7 ] ] }
```

However, the following (the same value at a deeper level):

```
ConvertTo-Json (ConvertFrom-Json '{ "abc": { "abc": [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, [5, 6, 7] ] } }')
```

returns:

```
{ "abc":  { "abc":  [ "1 2 3", 4, "5 6 7" ] } }
```

Is this a bug?

Ideally, I'd like to find out what PowerShell value to pass to `ConvertTo-Json` in order to produce the JSON in the 2nd example, i.e.:

```
'{ "abc": { "abc": [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, [5, 6, 7] ] } }'
```

I usually use `ConvertFrom-Json` to find out such values.

Comment: One suspects that Powershell has a limitation as to how "deep" JSON structures can be.

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849922.aspx the default depth is 2.

Answer (score 4):

Passing `-Depth 3` to `ConvertTo-Json` solves the problem:

```
ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 3 (ConvertFrom-Json '{ "abc": { "abc": [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 4, [5, 6, 7] ] } }')
```

produces:

```
{"abc":{"abc":[[1,2,3],4,[5,6,7]]}}
```